# iptables and limit requests per IP per minute

Tags: linux, debian, security, iptables

I'm running `Debian` and `iptables` and are trying to limit users to accept my site more than 10 times per minute.

This is my original attempt:

```
# Max connection in seconds
TIME_PERIOD=60
# Max connections per IP
BLOCKCOUNT=10

# default action can be DROP or REJECT
DACTION="DROP"

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds $TIME_PERIOD --hitcount $BLOCKCOUNT -j $DACTION
```

And I've also tried this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 8443 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT
```

But none if them seems to work.

Running this script for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="76.44.126.11"
port="8443"
for i in {1..100}
do
  # do nothing just connect and exit
  echo "exit" | nc ${ip} ${port};
done
```

Simply gives me this in `iptables -nvL` when I've run it twice:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 6 packets, 820 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/32 > 50 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
  200 12800 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
```

So it seems to simply allow all packets through...

What to do?

**UPDATE**

I need to put `--set` first, so now it's:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0            tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
  100  6400 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
```

But still fails.

**UPDATE**

Removed `eth0` so now it is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 19 packets, 4244 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
  101  6464 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
```

Same result, fails.

Comment: Does the IP in your script `76.44.126.11` belong to the same machine? Are you sure the traffic is coming via interface `eth0`?

Comment: I've removed `eth0` now, so I've got: `101  6464 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443`

Comment: Could it be due to `-m state --state NEW` or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `iptables -I` instead of `iptables -A`. This causes your rules to be in the reverse order. The option `-I` means to insert the rule at head of chain (when no rule number is specified).

The rule using `--set` option should be first, and the second rule should be the one that drops traffic when exceeding defined limit.

Comment: Reversed it, so now I've got `SET` first, but same result. Updated questions with output.

Comment: Worked with completely wipe of iptables. Is it completely the same to do `--seconds 10 --hitcount 20` as `--seconds 1 --hitcount 2`, meaning is it OK to go as low as `seconds 10` or even `seconds 1` if I want to allow a few per second?

Comment: So what is now the solution exactly?

Comment: Yeah there were many edits with no final answer :(